# How to exclude some rows from a SELECT Statement when 2 keys match?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables in my system: **Courses**, **Scores** and **Users**. Scores is a table which has the test results for each course and each user. So I have the ScoreID, The CourseID the UserID and the Score itself.

I want to show in some page the list of courses that the user didn't finished yet. So I want it to show all the courses excluding those the user has records in the Scores table (meaning he already has finished it).

How do I exclude the rows from a SELECT statement when certain CourseID and UserID match at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is for just one user, Mark Bannister's answer can be simplified a little...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Courses
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Scores WHERE CourseID = Courses.CourseID AND UserID = @userID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select *
from Courses c
cross join Users u
where not exists
(select null from Scores s where s.CourseID = c.CourseID and s.UserID = u.UserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `SQL Server` you can

- `CROSS APPLY` the courses and users, creating every possible combinations of courses and users
- use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out those records where a `UserID` exists.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT *
FROM   Courses c
       CROSS APPLY Users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   Scores
         WHERE  UserID = u.UserID
                AND ScoreID = c.ScoreID
       )
```

In case you are using any other DBMS, following *should* work on most DBMS's

```
SELECT *
FROM   Courses AS c
       , Users AS u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   Scores
         WHERE  UserID = u.UserID
                AND ScoreID = c.ScoreID
       )
```

Comment: By `CROSS APPLY` do you mean `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: @Dems - AFAIK, it doesn't matter in this case *(or does it)*?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Courses
where not exists
      (
          select null from Scores where Scores.CourseID = Courses.CourseID
                                    and Scores.UserID = Courses.UserID
      )
```